# MySQL select comments for friends then other comments while chronological order

Tags: mysql, sql, database, comments

This question could asked somewhere before but I could not find it, anyways.

So I have a video record that has many comments, each comment belongs to a user. The user on the other hand has many user friends.

Now, when user X signs in and view video Y I want to display the comments of his friends first (ordered by most recent). Then list other comments ordered with most recent.

I would prefer to make this logic in one single query if possible.

Thanks,

Comment: Some code to work off of would make this easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ORDER BY, do something like the following. Please know that I have know idea what your schema looks like, so this query won't work. But just create a 1/0 value indicating whether or not the user is a friend, and then order by that first, and then order by the posting / comment id afterwards

```
SELECT
    posting.id,
    IF(a.friend_id = b.criteria, 1, 0) AS is_friend
...
ORDER BY is_friend DESC, posting.id DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
Select comment of friends of X on video Y order by date
Union
Select comment on video Y where they is not friend of X order by date
```

Comment: Did you try it? `Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY` is what you will likely get with this approach.

Comment: [It is not that hard to verify with a simple example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/908c7/1) (Could be even simpler than mine, but you get the idea.)

Comment: What I wrote just idea. If you want sql, white sql correctly. [Follow this link to write syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)
What you gave via fiddle @AndriyM just forgot to put `()` in every select statement.

Comment: Here this your edited code : 
 `(SELECT * FROM comments WHERE IsFriend = 1 ORDER BY Date DESC)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM comments WHERE IsFriend = 0 ORDER BY Date DESC)`

Comment: Yes, I know that adding the brackets fixes the issue, but thanks for linking to a manual page that confirms it. Actually, that page contains the following statement: `[...] However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows. [...]` As you can see, the doc indicates that final result set in your case would be unordered, despite both subselects' having their own `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: @AndriyM Ok then, if you still need sql. Here is one of for your code. `(SELECT *,1 as f FROM comments WHERE IsFriend = 1)
UNION
(SELECT *,2 as f FROM comments WHERE IsFriend = 0)
ORDER BY f, Date DESC`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10958/discussion-between-bitoshi-n-and-andriy-m)

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION.

```
(
  SELECT 1 AS sort,*
  FROM comments
  INNER JOIN friends ON comments.poster_id=friends.friend_id
  WHERE friends.id='123'
)
UNION
(
  SELECT 2 AS sort,*
  FROM comments
  WHERE poster_id NOT IN(SELECT friend_id FROM friend WHERE id='123')
)
ORDER BY sort,time DESC
```

Comment: But is the order guaranteed to be retained after the two subqueries are united with `UNION`?

Comment: Thanks to bitoshi.n, I found a [manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) that confirms that the result of UNION is in fact unordered regardless of individual SELECTs' having explicit `ORDER BY`s. You need an `ORDER BY` clause for the entire query to guarantee ordering.

Comment: Easy. Add sort column and add it as first priority order in ORDER BY statement.

Comment: Now that there's no individual ORDER BYs, the parentheses around SELECTs are unnecessary (although they may appear helpful in that they outline the query layout nicely). Still, this will not compile, because the number of columns in both parts of UNION does not match. I guess you meant to write `comments.*` instead of just `*` in the first SELECT.